# Phonegap: Remove Save discard confimation after taking photo

Tags: android, cordova, android-camera

I am using following camera api in phonegap 1.8 for android 2.3 to capture pictures in loop.

`navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });`

After taking the picture, it is showing a confirmation to save or discard data. Is there anyway i can prevent that confirmation dialog and do a 'Save' by default.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The phone gap uses the android camera app to capture the picture. The camera app doesn't give user the option to disable the confirmation screen.

Therefore this is not possible with existing phonegap api.

However we can write a custom app using the Camera library in android. (see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera))

We can then build a phonegap plugin to use this app. (see [this](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android))